# Possible Error with the Output Graph

Tags: graphics, numerical-integration

I'm running the following command:

```
G = 0.01;
ωc = 15;
β = 1;
ω0 = 11;

integral1 =   G ω Exp[-ω/ωc]  Sinc^2[((ω - 1) t)/2];


Plot[1 - 2 t^2 NIntegrate[integral1, {ω, 0, Infinity}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15], {t, 0, 
10000000000}]
```

The output I get is: [image]

It is clear from the function I am trying to plot that at t = , the value of the dependent variable is 1. But the graph shows that the value of the dependent variable is 1 for all values of t, something I don't expect considering that there are both exponential and sinusoidal functional dependence.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

`Sinc^2[_]` is wrong and should be `Sinc[_]^2` unless you mean `Sinc[Sinc[_]]`.

`integral1` should be defined as a function because it depends on `t` and `ω`. For some reason `NIntegrate` happen to transform the integrand through `ω` into a non-numeric expression (which is obviously wrong) unless it is prevented by the syntax `ω_?NumericQ`.

```
G = 0.01;
ωc = 15;
β = 1;
ω0 = 11;
integral1[t_, ω_?NumericQ] = G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] Sinc[((ω - 1) t)/2]^2;

Plot[1 - 2 t^2 NIntegrate[integral1[t, ω], {ω, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive",
                           MaxRecursion -> 15], {t, 0, 10000000000}]
```

Comment: `Sinc^2[_]` is certainly not the same as `Sinc[Sinc[_]]`

Comment: @mikado `% /. Power[f_, n_Integer] :> Composition @@ Table[f, {n}]`